# Schmidt decomposition for Matrix Product State in canonical form

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, tensor-network

During a lecture on comp. Quantum Phyiscs the concept of [Matrix Product States (MPS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_product_state) (with open boundry conditions) was introduced in the form
$$\vert\psi\rangle = \sum_{i_1,\dots,i_n}\psi_{i_1\dots i_n} \vert i_1,\dots,i_n\rangle := A^{[1]i_1}\dots A^{[n] i_n} \vert i_1,\dots,i_n\rangle,$$
where the first and last matrix are vectors to guarantee that $\psi_{i_1\dots i_n}\in\mathbb{C}$. Shortly after the *canonical form* was introduced as
$$\psi_{i_1\dots i_n} := \Lambda^{[1]} \Gamma^{[1]i_1}\dots \Lambda^{[n]} \Gamma^{[n] i_n},$$
which amounts to a redefinition $A^{[k]i_k} =:\Lambda^{[k]}\Gamma^{[k]i_k}$ where $\Lambda^{[k]}$ is a identiy matrix multiplied by a [singular value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) and $\Gamma^{[k]i_k}$ a suitable matrix.

My Prof. now clamied in the lecture that via a [Schmidt decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt_decomposition) we can achieve the form
$$\mid \psi\rangle = \sum_\alpha \vert\alpha\rangle_L\, \lambda_\alpha\, \vert\alpha\rangle_R. $$ I don't really understand how one is supposed to achive this and I couldn't really find a clear explanation anywhere... I think [these](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.00055.pdf) lecture notes attempt to explain it (going from eq. (18) to eq. (20)) but I can't really follow. How exactly does one construct the states $\vert\alpha\rangle_R$ and $\vert\alpha\rangle_L$ from $\vert i_1,\dots,i_n\rangle$?

Comment: To get the last form you quote from the previous one you don't need a Schmidt decomposition.  Note that to get this form the structure of the $\Gamma$ is essential.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I just looked thorugh my notes and couldn't find any special recuirements on the structure of $\Gamma$.. I'm sorry, but could you maybe elaborate how one gets to the last equation?

Comment: Please use @[username] to ping me otherwise I don't get notified of your comments. -- If there are no special requirements on $\Gamma$ then something is missing in your notes.  The idea of the $\Gamma$-$\Lambda$ form is that if you contract the chain at any cut from the left *or* from the right (terminating at the $\Lambda$) you get the identity, so at every cut the corresponding $\Lambda$ contains the Schmidt coefficients.

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3477, Section 4.6.  In particular Eqs. (163-165) (the condition on $\Gamma$, and (169) (the Schmidt decomposition).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Hmm, thanks for the paper. If I'm not missunderstanding I need to add dummy $\Gamma^{[n+1]i_{n+1}} = 1$ to the expression for $\psi_{i_1,\dots,i_n}$ to make sure that I can achive the form $$(\Lambda^{[1]} \Gamma)(\Lambda^{[2]} \Gamma) \ldots(\Lambda^{[\ell-2]} \Gamma)(\Lambda^{[\ell-1]} \Gamma) \Lambda^{[\ell]}(\Gamma \Lambda^{[\ell+1]})(\Gamma \Lambda^{[\ell+2]})\dots (\Gamma \Lambda^{[n+1]}).$$ Then you take $\vert \alpha\rangle _L := (\Lambda^{[1]} \Gamma)(\Lambda^{[2]} \Gamma) \ldots(\Lambda^{[\ell-2]} \Gamma)(\Lambda^{[\ell-1]} \Gamma)\vert i_1,\dots, i_{\ell -1} \rangle$?